# Problem regarding proving a permutation group

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, permutations

The question states:

> Show that the set of permutations of three objects form a group. Give the multiplication table for this group.

If we take three distinct objects, the set of the permutations will have cardinality 6. How do we prove it's a group? And how do we make a multiplication table? I'm new to groups so I don't have a firm grasp over the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Getting some notation should help.

Let the set of three objects be $\{1,2,3\}$. An example of a permutation then is $(12)$. This notation means that object $2$ takes the place of object $1$, and object $1$ takes the place of object $2$. An example of a permutation of three objects is $(123)$, meaning $3$ takes the place of $2$, $2$ takes the place of $1$, and $1$ takes the place of $3$. In general, we work from right to left.

An example of multiplication is $(12)(23)$. To determine what this equals, we see how it acts on each element of the set. What happens when we perform this permutation on object $1$? Working from right to left, we see that the first permutation does not affect object $1$, but the second permutation sends $1$ to $2$. The first permutation sends $2$ to $3$, but the second one doesn't affect $3$. Lastly, the first permutation sends $3$ to $2$, and the second permutation sends $2$ to $1$. So $1$ gets sent to $2$, $2$ gets sent to $3$, and $3$ gets sent to $1$. Hence, we have $(12)(23) = (321)$.

Hopefully these examples are illustrative enough to get you started.

Comment: I get what you've explained so far so thanks. But how do I show that the permutation forms a group? What will be the identity? And the operation will simply be the permutation right?

Comment: The identity is given by the permutation that does nothing, sending 1 to 1, 2 to 2, and 3 to 3. You can denote it by $e$. The permutations are the elements of the group, and the group operation is multiplication of permutations as I explained above. Also show that every element has an inverse.

Comment: So if (1 2 3) is the identity, and (3 2 1), (3 1 2), (2 1 3), (2 3 1) and (1 3 2) are the other elements of the set, by multiplication table of the group does it mean that we have to multiply the individual elements with each other or just with the identity?

Comment: Let's start over. To determine the elements of the group, consider what action the permutation has on the elements of the set. $(123)$ sends 3 to 2, so it cannot be the identity. The identity is simply denoted by $e$. Furthermore, look at $(321),(213),$ and $(132)$. They are all the same permutation, because they have the same effect on the elements of the set. The elements of the group will be the identity, 3 transpositions (permutations that switch two elements), and 2 3-cycles (permutations that change the position of all the elements). See if you can determine what they are.

Answer (score 1):

A group is a set X together with a map $f : X\times X->X$ (If the (ordered!) pair $(a,b)$
 is mapped to $c$, this is denoted with $a*b=c$, where "*" does not necessariliy mean
 the multiplication), such that the following properties hold :

There is an element $e$, called neutral element with the property $x*e=x$ for all $x$

For every $x$, there is a $y$ (called inverse of $x$) with $x*y=e$

For all $x,y,z$, the equation $x*(y*z)=(x*y)*z$ holds (rule of associativity)

Now, in our case, with "*" it is meant that the permutations act one after another.

For example

p : 1 2 3

```
 2 3 1
```

q : 1 2 3

```
 3 2 1
```

We have

p*q : 1 2 3

```
   2 1 3
```

The neutral element is the idendity permutation

id : 1 2 3

```
  1 2 3
```

Comment: Feel free to ask if something is still unclear.

Comment: So the identity is ( 1 2 3), but how and why did you choose that combination of permutations for p and q? How did you get the answer by multiplying p and q?

Comment: permutation $p$ sends $1$ to $2$. And permutation $q$ sends $2$ to $2$. So, permutation $p*q$ sends $1$ to $2$. The element $2$ is sent to $3$ and this to $1$. Finally, $3$ is sent to $1$ and this to $3$

Comment: It is easy to find the inverse permutation : Looking at permuation $p$ upwards, we see that $1$ is sent to $3$, $2$ is sent to $1$ and $3$ is sent to $2$, so $p^{-1}=(3\ 1\ 2)$

Answer (score 0):

The group you are considering is $S_{3}$, the symmetries (permutations) over three elements. The operation is function composition. So you need to show a few things to prove it is a group:

-The operation is associative

-The operation is closed (given two elements $\sigma_{1}, \sigma_{2} \in S_{3}$, is $\sigma_{1} \odot \sigma_{2} \in S_{3}$)

-The operation is invertible (for every $\sigma$, there exists $\sigma^{-1}$ such that $\sigma \sigma^{-1} = \sigma^{-1} \sigma = 1$.

-There is an identity element (this is easy- the identity mapping)

So think of permutations as bijections: $\pi : S \to S$, where $S$ is your set.

For invertibility, just undo the mapping. So consider the table:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ \sigma(1) & \sigma(2) & \sigma(3) \end{bmatrix}$$

Giving us a permutation. If $\sigma$ sends $3 \mapsto \sigma(3)$, then $\sigma^{-1}$ must take $\sigma(3) \mapsto 3$. Can you construct a $\sigma^{-1}$ given $\sigma$?

Once you understand how to prove it is a group, the multiplication table should follow easier.